# Write Sql Query

Tags: sql-server

We have a table with three columns (`Name_of_office`, `Month`, `Amount`), as below:

```
Name_Of_Office      Month     Amount
------------------------------------
DivisionBhopal      04         125
DivisionBhopal      05          50
DivisionBhopal      06         100
DivisionBhopal      10         125
DivisionSagar       04         600
DivisionSagar       05         520
DivisionSagar       06         400
DivisionSagar       10         100
```

Financial Year Month should be used for calculation.

By the formula always start sum from April to selected month.

Suppose user will select month of June (from dropdown)

Calculation should be performed like this

```
Name_Of_Office     Sum Upto Previous Month    Present Month   Total Amount
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DivisionBhopa      April + May                June            April + May+ June 
DivisionSagar      April  + May               June            April + May+ June
```

Here we will not add oct amount because selected Month is June we want data till June

For month of June, data should look like:

```
Name_Of_Office     Sum Upto Previous Month   Present Month    Total  Amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DivisionBhopal           175                     100              275
DivisionSagar           1120                     400             1520
```

For October data should look like (if user selects December):

```
Name_Of_Office     Sum Upto Previous Month   Present Month      Total  Amount
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DivisionBhopal          275                      125                400
Divisionsagar          1520                      100               1620
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: For best results, reduce your question down to a single specific request, clearly explain what you want that to be and what you have done so far that is not working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE***  highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
    SELECT A.NAME_OF_OFFICE, B.SUM_UPTO_PREV_MONTH, A.AMOUNT,B.SUM_UPTO_CURR_MONTH
FROM TEMP A
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT NAME_OF_OFFICE, SUM(AMOUNT) SUM_UPTO_PREV_MONTH
FROM  TEMP
GROUP BY NAME_OF_OFFICE
WHERE MONTH < 6
) B ON A.NAME_OF_OFFICE = B.NAME_OF_OFFICE
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT NAME_OF_OFFICE, SUM(AMOUNT) SUM_UPTO_CURR_MONTH
FROM  TEMP
GROUP BY NAME_OF_OFFICE
WHERE MONTH <= 6
) C ON A.NAME_OF_OFFICE = C.NAME_OF_OFFICE
WHERE A.MONTH = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional agregations:

```
select office,
sum(amount)as total,
sum(case when month = @passedmonth then amount else 0 end) as present,
sum(case when month < @passedmonth then amount else 0 end) as prev
from table
where month >= 4 and month < @passedmonth
group by office
```

Comment: You probably meant your `where` condition to be `month >= 4 and month <= @passedmonth` (or just `month between 4 and @passedmonth` for brevity).